# Why is interface builder not showing my unwind segue?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, interface-builder

My app's navigation flow looks a bit like this:

**UINavigationController - MasterViewController > DetailViewController > InfoViewController**

MasterViewController contains the following method:

```
@IBAction func unwindToMaster(with segue: UIStoryboardSegue) {}
```

In DetailViewController, there is a similar method:

```
@IBAction func unwindToDetail(with segue: UIStoryboardSegue) {}
```

I use these methods, along with UIButtons, to allow the user to advance forward and back through the navigation hierarchy. In interface builder, I see the method under DetailViewController when I right click on "Exit" in InfoViewController, but when I right click on "Exit" in DetailViewController, no other unwind segues are listed.

I have consulted multiple online sources (Ray Wenderlich, relevant StackOverflow questions) instructing the correct way to produce unwind segues in interface builder, but none of these have helped solve the issue. Right now, I need help figuring out **what the problem is** in the first place. As development usually goes, it's probably something staring me square in the face.

[image: Exit Menu in DetailViewController — 'unwindToPersonWith:' = 'unwindToDetail']

I am running Xcode 8.1 using Swift 3. Thank you.

Comment: I've seen it take a few rebuilds sometimes for Xcode to find all of the relevant unwind segues. If you clean, rebuild, and then reopen the storyboard, does that help at all?

Comment: I would suggest deleting the word "with" and replacing it by underscore (`_`). That is what is expected here.

Comment: I tried your suggestion a few times, @ChrisVig, but it didn't change anything in the storyboard. In the past, how many times have you had to rebuild for interface builder to catch up?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, @matt, but replacing `with` with `_` didn't cause the first method to show up in interface builder.

Comment: @blutie normally only once or twice, so it sounds like this is probably a different issue.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

To re-iterate: not only an Action for a Storyboard Unwind Segue has to be placed in the same source file as `class` definition for an unwind-to (destination) View Controller (e.g., `@IBAction func prepareForUnwind(segue: UIStoryboardSegue)`, detected as `prepareForUnwind[With]Segue` in a "Presenting Segues" list), but also that View Controller **cannot have ANY extensions in ANY secondary source files**. You have to merge `class` definition and all extensions into a single source file.

(As of Xcode 8.2.1.)

Comment: I never would have thought of this. Rather than a subclass, mine used a type alias. Making it a straight subclass fixed the issue.

Answer (score 8):

In my case, I had a complicated inheritance in my view controller and it was a reason why Interface Builder did not see my unwind. So this workaround works for me well:

1. Go to `YouCollViewController.swift` file and delete all classes, protocols, generics, etc. your view controller implements in view controller's declaration
2. Inherit your view controller from `UIViewController`
3. Go to the storyboard and connect your action with the `unwind`, it should appear in unwinds list
4. Go back to `YouCollViewController.swift` file and discard all the changes

Comment: This worked for me in XCode 11. I had to change my destination view controller to inherit from UIViewController and then the unwind segue showed up in the Exit

Answer (score 3):

I consulted Apple's Developer Library (specifically the page ["Using Unwind Segues"](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/technotes/tn2298/_index.html)). There, the example definition of an unwind action is:

```
@IBAction func unwindToMainMenu(sender: UIStoryboardSegue) {
    let sourceViewController = sender.sourceViewController
    // Pull any data from the view controller which initiated the unwind segue.
}
```

Applying this example in my code, I changed my unwind action declarations to:

```
@IBAction func unwindToMaster(sender: UIStoryboardSegue) {
    print("Unwinded to master.")
}
```

and

```
@IBAction func unwindToDetail(sender: UIStoryboardSegue) {
    print("Unwinded to detail.")
}
```

I also made sure that each method was contained within the same file as MasterViewController's class declaration. After further testing, I found that all extensions of MasterViewController had to exist **in the same file** for interface builder to find and recognize the unwind segue.

Now, in storyboard, the exit menu shows both unwind segues. My conclusion is that by fiddling around with where the methods are placed and how they are declared, a configuration that interface builder can recognize will be found. I hope it will be less touchy in the future, as my current method organization is very long and difficult to navigate.

[image]

Comment: I had the same issue -- my method signature was correct but I had an extension in another file. Moving it back to the same file fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

Because none of these answers helped me and I didn't want to mess around with my code that much. Here another solution you can give a try.

Starting from the point where you have already added the unwind function to your MasterViewController.

1. First I have gone ahead and added a new ViewController to my storyboard as well as a new Cocoa Touch Class File of type UIViewController and connected it with my Storyboard one (I called it the HelperViewController).
2. Then you can add the same unwind function, you already have inside your MasterVC to your newly created HelperVC.

   `@IBAction func unwindToMaster(with segue: UIStoryboardSegue) {}`
3. Now connect the Helper to your DetailVC. Your Storyboard should look somewhat like mine. You should get the same option as me if you ctrl + drag and drop to the exit of your DetailVC. When the connection has been established and you hover over the newly created segue both the Master and the HelperVC should be highlighted. Now you can delete the HelperVC again and everything should work as expected.

I hope that helped!

[image: My Storyboard]

Comment: Thanks for this solution. None of the above solutions had worked for me and this one did. It's 6 years later and the state of this convoluted, obscure "feature" still has the same quirks. A lot of time wasted, sigh!

Answer (score 0):

With swift 4 XCode 9.2 I found that you need to drag the reference from the yellow icon at the top of the viewController to the "Exit" reference of the target viewController in the left details panel. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes XCode restart makes the actions appear.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem, following the "Develop in Swift Fundamentals" book from Apple, Lesson 3.7, Segues and Navigation Controllers.

Page 498 shows Ctrl-dragging from the Dismiss button to the Exit button at the top of the View Controller on the Storyboard.  I could not get that to work.

However, what DID work was Ctrl-dragging from the Dismiss button to the Exit entry for that View Controller IN THE DOCUMENT OUTLINE rather than to the Exit button shown at the top of the View Controller (being dismissed) in the storyboard.  When I did that, I was presented the list of Unwind Segues, and when I Built and Ran the project in the simulator, it worked.

I also created a separate UIViewController subclass (File->New->File...->Cocoa Touch Class), selected the source ViewController in the storyboard (the one that you are dismissing), and in the Identity Inspector selected that new class under Custom Class/Class, and that worked.  However, it also worked without creating a new subclass.